# Is there any way to alter sequence name in HANA DB?

Tags: sql, sequence, ddl, hana

Is there any way to alter a sequence's name in HANA DB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no syntax to rename a sequence in Hana DB. However, note that a sequence doesn't carry too much data in it anyway - the simplest thing would be to create a new sequence with the same value and drop the old one.